# Replace a Canvas Pie Chart Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, chart.js

I have a pie chart created using chart.js

Here is the code for that:

```
            var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
            var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);

            var PieData = [
              {
                  value: 700,
                  color: "#f56954",
                  highlight: "#f56954",
                  label: "Chrome"
              },
              {
                  value: 500,
                  color: "#00a65a",
                  highlight: "#00a65a",
                  label: "IE"
              },
              {
                  value: 400,
                  color: "#f39c12",
                  highlight: "#f39c12",
                  label: "FireFox"
              }
       pieChart.Doughnut(PieData);

<canvas id="pieChart" style="width:60%; height:60%;"></canvas>
```

I want to create a few different pie charts representing different information but only want to ever display one pie chart at a time. So when i click on a drop down menu i want another pie chart to appear. Basically using the same code as above but changing the information in the pieData[].

The code for changing using the list is

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="">Device</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that only data will be changed because you want the same canvas for everything, you can create a function which draw the data on the canvas everytime is called (See the function receive as first parameter the data that will be displayed in the canvas)

```
function selectData(id){
     if(id == 1){
       var data = []; //whatever i want to draw when option 1 is selected!
       DrawChart(data);
     }

     if(id == 2){
       var data = []; //whatever i want to draw when option 2 is selected!
       DrawChart(data);
     }
}

function DrawChart(data){    

    var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas).Pie(data);
    //Demo with official documentation http://www.chartjs.org/docs/
    //var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx[0]).Pie(data,options);
    //var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx[1]).Doughnut(data,options);
}
```

so, you are not using a html Select widget, you are using a UL for this, you can use :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="selectData(1);">Browsers</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="selectData(2);">Other things</a></li>
</ul>
```

Although you can design a better mode to solve your problem, this is a quick solution that will help you to understand how to draw data dinamically with Chart.js